# Azure Pipelines Task - How to dynamically populate a pickList input with a source other than a service endpoint?

Tags: json, typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-tasks, azure-pipelines-task-lib

In the link to the custom task, below, you'll see several pickList fields; one for the service endpoint, two for environment and command, which are static lists in the task.json, and then a fourth. This one, I need to be populated with a list of items dependent on the selection of the environment, but there is no (functioning) endpoint I can bind this input to in order to get that list. There is, however, a CLI command I can run to do this.

I've found plenty of documentation, and forum answers, on how to use the connectedService type to populate a pickList, but none on how to do it without a service endpoint. In addition, there is no "setInput" equivalent in the Azure-Pipelines-Task-Lib TypeScript API.

Is this even possible with custom tasks, at this point? If so, what are some options that I can look into?

Custom Task
[image: Custom Task]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this even possible with custom tasks, at this point? If so, what are some options that I can look into?

I am afraid this is impossible to create a custom task to dynamically populate a pickList input **without** service endpoint.

As we know, service endpoint provides the URL, authentication info to make the calls. Without that, we could not get the HTTP Get call. That the key point of this issue.

Besides, Azure devops currently don't support data source bindings to associate to task input to query a public URL. MS will consider adding this support going forward.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

Hope this helps.